# Program for finding square root of number

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

So I wrote a program to find floor of square of a number. It seems to work fine for smaller numbers but for long numbers it gives weird results. Here is my code.

```
int SquareRoot(long x)
{
  long start=1;
  long end=x;
  long mid;

  while(start<end)
  {
     mid=start+(end-start+1)/2;
     if(mid*mid<x)
     {
        if((mid+1)*(mid+1)>x)
        {
            return mid;
        }
       start=mid;
     }
     else if(mid*mid>x)
     {

         if((mid-1)*(mid-1<x)
            return mid-1;
        end=mid;
    }
    else
        return mid;
  }
  return start;
}
```

Comment: "it gives weird results" is not a valid question. You need to be more specific, and concise.

Comment: Oh sorry. I cannot track down the relation between expected output and actual output on bigger numbers but here are some examples of what I got for output on these numbers.

Comment: "Cannot track down"? Mind to elaborate?

Comment: Here is the output of some big numbers:                                                                     Input: 7777777 Output: 393225                                                                                     Input: 990000 Output: 173384                                                                                          Input: 1000000 Output: 458753                                                                                            .

Comment: By "Cannot track down the relation" I meant that these output results seem random to me. I cannot find a consistent error(off by some constant amount) in them

Comment: As @rici said, some multiplication may overflow. Perhaps you could use `long long` instead of `long`. Furthermore, I don't think binary search is a good approach to solve the square root problem. Obviously there are better ways to predict a closer range.

Comment: @HenryLee What other approach can I use?

Comment: @s_123 Because the square root is much closer to 1 instead of x / 2, it would be better if we start trying from the left, and consequently your overflow issue won't occur. You can try g = 1 in the first step, test `g * g` and `(g+1) * (g+1)`. If it is not the correct candidate, iterate with `g = (g + x / g) / 2`. You can see that there is an invariant `g <= sqrt(x)`, making sure you won't get pass the correct candidate.

Comment: Lets say x is 9. If I start with g=1, I'll see that its not correct candidate yet. Then g becomes 5 with that formula. How does that invariant work?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the "weird results" you observe happen when one or both of the computations `mid * mid` and `(mid + 1) * (mid + 1)` overflows, which will happen when `end` is bigger than `2*sqrt(LONG_MAX)` (approximately 6,074,000,998 if `long` is 64 bits, or 92680 if `long` is 32 bits).

The overflow will cause the comparison with `x` to produce an erroneous result (technically, the overflow produces Undefined Behaviour although with gcc the result is predictable but incorrect).

Comment: I also guessed this because this LONG_MAX number is 10 digits and my program seems to work fine when the number is 5 digits or less.

Comment: @s_123: LONG_MAX varies from platform to platform but it must be at least 2147483647 (2^31-1). Another common value is 9223372036854775807 (2^63-1).

Comment: yeah..seems like mine is the former one. Thanks :)